# Python - Open file in notepad that is contained in a variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I couldn't find this anywhere, so sorry if I missed it.  It seems like it should be simple but somehow isn't.  I have a simple program that opens a log (log1.lg let's say) and strips any lines that don't contain keywords.  It then tosses them into a 2nd file that is renamed to Log1.lg.clean.

The way I've implemented this is by using os.rename so the code looks like this:

```
#define source and key words
source_log = 'Log1.lg'
bad_words = ['word', 'bad']

#clean up the log
with open(source_log) as orig_log, open('cleanlog.lg', 'w') as cleanlog:

     for line in orig_log:
         if not any9bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
              cleanlog.write(line)

#rename file and open in Notepad
rename = orig_log + '.clean'
new_log = os.rename("cleanlog.lg", rename)
prog = "notepad.exe"
subprocess.Popen(prog, new_log)
```

Error I'm getting is this:

```
File "C:\Users\me\Downloads\PythonStuff\stripMmax.py", line 23, in cleanLog
    subprocess.Popen(prog, new_log)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 339, in __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
```

I'm using Python 2.7 if that's relevant.  I don't get why this isn't working or why it's requiring a bufsize.  I've seen other examples where this works this way so I'm thinking maybe this command doesn't work in 2.7 the way I'm typing it?

The documentation shows how to use this properly using the actual file name in quotes, but as you can see, mine here is contained in a variable which seems to cause issues.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

See the `Popen` constructor here: [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). The second argument to `Popen` is `bufsize`. That explains your error. Also note that `os.rename` does not return anything so `new_log` will be `None`. Use your `rename` variable instead. Your call should look like this:

```
subprocess.Popen([prog, rename])
```

You likely also want to wait on the created `Popen` object:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen([prog, rename])
proc.wait()
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Thanks @FamousJameous.  I tried that and now I get the following:

  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 262, in list2cmdline
    needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: The line of code that throws that exception is not in the code you posted. Please update your question so that I can see the context of the line `needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg`.

Comment: @user1578881 Sorry, I misread your exception. If you haven't already figured it out, the problem is that one of your variables is `None`. Looking at your code, it looks like new_log would be `None` since `os.rename` does not return anything. You should use `rename` instead of `new_log` in the `Popen`.